# Qt - How to get real size of maximized window that I have pointer to?

Tags: qt, window-resize

I have a method that get pointer to widget where should be setted some other widgets. I have to resize the main window, where that widget is placed and then I should get the real size of that widget.

I’ve tried to do this like:

```
void MyClass::setWidgets(QList<QWidget*> list, QWidget *parentWidget)
{
    QWidget* mainWindow = parentWidget->window();
    mainWindow->showMaximized();

    int width = parentWidget->size().width();
    int height = parentWidget->size().height();
    /*... rest of method...*/
}
```

That method is call from other class.
But I read that I should wait for resizeEvent. Could anyone explain me how I should do this or if there is any option to get that size differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get events for a different object, you can install an event filter using [`QObject::installEventFilter`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter).

A simple example for `ResizeEvent` is:

**filter.hpp**

```
#ifndef FILTER_HPP
#define FILTER_HPP

#include <QtGui>

class ResizeFilter : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    ResizeFilter();
  protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);
};

#endif
```

**filter.cpp**

```
#include "filter.hpp"

ResizeFilter::ResizeFilter() : QObject() {}

bool ResizeFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
  if (event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
  {
    QResizeEvent* resizeEv = static_cast<QResizeEvent*>(event);
    qDebug() << resizeEv->size();
  }
  return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "filter.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  ResizeFilter filter;

  QWidget window;
  window.installEventFilter(&filter);
  window.showMaximized();

  return app.exec();
}
```

**filter.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app
HEADERS = filter.hpp
SOURCES = main.cpp filter.cpp
```

---

When testing this on my PC it gave the output:

```
QSize(840, 420) 
QSize(1280, 952)
```